# How to determine the maximum number of times the DES algorithm needs to be run?

Tags: algorithm-design, des, multiple-encryption

I am only a beginner in cryptography and I am getting confused by the following:

### Question

Consider a known-plaintext attack performed on a double-DES cryptosystem.

(a) Determine the maximum number of times the DES algorithm needs to be run when
using the brute-force strategy.

(b) Determine the maximum number of times the DES algorithm needs to be run when
using the meet-in-the-middle strategy.

### My Answer

These are what I think is correct, please let me know if i am wrong, Thank you!

a) Double DES uses a key length of 112. Therefore brute force will take maximum 2^112 attempts to break double DES.

b) DES has a key space of 2^56. Double DES has twice the security of DES, therefore it will have 2 * 2^56 = 2^57 security.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. For homework questions we provide hints. For you, simply search within DES tag.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but cant find the answers

Comment: Hint for a) Brute force means search all possible keys. b) is this attack for 2DES 3DES? or just single DES run half enc half dec?

Comment: So is a) 2^57 times? and for b) I was also unsure but i think its 2DES

Comment: Please look at the effective key size of DES in Wikipedia! For attacking 2DES there are lost of good answers in this site.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question please let me know if I am correct, Thank you!